# Find the coefficient of a power of x in the product of polynomials - Link with Combinations?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, multinomial-coefficients

I came across a new set of problems while studying combinatorics which involves restrictions to several variables and use of multinomial theoram to evaluate the number of possible combinations of the variables subjected to those restrictions.For example 
If we were to pick 6 balls out of a bag which contained 3 red , 4 green and 5 white identical balls then the method i've been taught is as follows :

Suppose

$a$ = red balls , $b$= green balls and $c$=white balls .

Now, 
$a +b+c =6$ where $0<=a<=3,0<=b<=4,0<=c<=5.$

Now i am supposed to find the coefficient of $x^6$ in the following product :
$(1+x^1+x^2+x^3)(1+x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4)(1+x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)$ and that is the solution.

I want to understand what's actually happening here since finding a coefficient seems to have no link with the possible combinations. THANKS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider for a moment the product

$$\left(x^0+x^1+x^2+x^3\right)\left(y^0+y^1+y^2+y^3+y^4\right)\left(z^0+z^1+z^2+z^3+z^4+z^5\right)\;.$$

When you multiply it out, you get a total of $4\cdot5\cdot6=120$ terms, each of the form $x^ay^bz^c$, where $0\le a\le 3$, $0\le b\le 4$, and $0\le c\le 5$.

Now change the $y$’s and $z$’s back to $x$’s to get the original product; when multiplied out, it’s still a sum of $120$ terms, which are now of the form $x^ax^bx^c=x^{a+b+c}$, where $0\le a\le 3$, $0\le b\le 4$, and $0\le c\le 5$. The lowest power of $x$ in the product is clearly $x^0$, and the highest is $x^{3+4+5}=x^{12}$.

Suppose that $0\le n\le 12$; what’s the coefficient of $x^n$ in this product when we collect like terms? It’s simply the number of products $x^ax^bx^c$ for which $a+b+c=n$. In other words, the coefficient of $x^n$ in this product is the number of solutions to the equation $a+b+c=n$ such that $a,b$, and $c$ are integers satisfying the inequalities $0\le a\le 3$, $0\le b\le 4$, and $0\le c\le 5$. In your ball problem that’s the number of distinguishable combinations of $n$ red, green, and white balls that can be drawn from that particular bag.

Comment: Oh now it makes some sense to me, i also wanted some clarification on a note highlighted in my book that if upper limit of a variable is more than or equal to the required sum and lower limit is non-negative ,then the upper limit of that variable can be taken as infinite.Why is that so?

Comment: @Shrey606: Suppose, for example, that the required sum is $20$. If all of the variables are required to be non-negative, then the maximum possible value of any variable is $20$: to make one any bigger would require making one of the others negative. Thus, if the limit on $X_1$, say, is $20$ or more, there’s no way that any solution can exceed that limit, and you can ignore it: it’s as if there were no limit.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to think of it. Let's rewrite as $$(r^0+r^1+r^2+r^3)(g^0+g^1+g^2+g^3+g^4)(w^0+w^1+w^2+w^3+w^4+w^5),$$ for a moment. When we expand this, every single one of the terms will be of the form $r^ag^bw^c.$ This gives us a one-to-one correspondence with the various ways in which the balls can be drawn--where $r^ag^bw^c$ represents the situation of drawing $a$ red balls, $b$ green balls, and $c$ white balls. Now, if we no longer wish to distinguish between the various ways we can draw a certain *number* of balls of *any* type, then we can set $r,g,w=x$ to get your original expression. The coefficient of $x^6,$ then, will be the number of terms $r^ag^bw^c$ such that $a+b+c=6$--that is, the number of ways we can draw $6$ balls of any type, as desired.